# Kendo change snippets name ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-editor

I have a kendo editor, I use the snippets feature but I want to change the display text on it, currently it shows "HTML toevoegen" which means "Insert HTML". Now I want to change this to "Placeholders".

[image: What it shows]

This is the code I already have:

```
<div class="div6 editor-field">
@(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(x => x.MailBodyEN)
.Name("EditorEN")
.Tools(tools => tools
            .Clear()
            .Bold()
            .Italic()
            .Underline()
            .Strikethrough()
            .JustifyLeft()
            .JustifyCenter()
            .JustifyRight()
            .JustifyFull()
            .InsertUnorderedList()
            .InsertOrderedList()
            .Outdent()
            .Indent()
            .CreateLink()
            .Unlink()
            .SubScript()
            .SuperScript()
            .TableEditing()
            .ViewHtml()
            .Formatting()
            .CleanFormatting()
            .FontName()
            .FontSize()
            .BackColor()
            .FontColor()
            .Snippets(snippets => snippets
                .Add("Aanhef", "{{AANHEF}}")
                .Add("Contactpersoon", "{{CONTACTPERSOON}}")
                .Add("Kwartaal", "{{KWARTAAL}}")
                .Add("Jaar", "{{JAAR}}")
                .Add("Declaratielink", "{{DECLARATIELINK}}")
                .Add("Slot", "{{GROET}}"))
            )
.Resizable(true))
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.MailBodyEN)
```

Now the problem is, online I can find the Javascript way to do it: which is the way to do it if ou made it the Javascript way, using messages. I want to do it the C# way, I saw it has a .Messages method I can call:

[image: messages]

But I dont know what to put between the brackets to change the text from "HTML toevoegen" to  "Placeholders".

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out and it works now, I dont now why I didnt think about this before. but it was literally like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.